# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 to mysql container inside jenkins

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using docker-slaves plugin to create mysql container inside jenkins. The complete setup is running at localhost. I am not able to connect to mysql container from my node.js script.

```
error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

The connection script is as follows:

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: mysqlHost,
  user: mysqlUser,
  password: mySqlPassword,
  database: mysqlDb
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    //return;
  }
  //console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

> Jenkins job configuration with docker-slaves plugin :

[image: jenkins-setup]

Comment: Is the container running? Does the container have the port exposed/mapped? Does the service run at 3306? Are you running that script inside the container, or from another container?

Comment: Yes, the container is running. Mysql exposes 3306 port by default for connections. I am calling the script inside the main build container.

Comment: So you are running the script inside your msql container? if so, can you post `netstat -ntlp` output, or check if anything is listening @ 3306

Comment: If you are running from the docker container, can you post `docker ps` output?

Comment: i am not running the script inside mysql container. It's running inside main docker container. docker ps is showing the list of running containers i.e .
1) jenkinsci/slave
2) main build container 
3) mysql

Comment: If that is the case, is port 3306 from the main container forwarded to the mysql container? if this is the case `docker ps` will show `3306 -> 3306`. If that is not the case, you should resolve it on the hostname/id of the container instead of `127.0.0.1`. You can do this by 1. giving it a name, ie mysql. and tehn query it `mysql:3306`; 2. query it by using the id: `<imageid>:3306`; 3. query it by the name docker gives it (you can see with `docker ps`, ie `akward_heisenberg:3306`. Also [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) might help

Comment: How do i publish port through docker-slaves plugin? I can't modify the run command as well as no docker-compose file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140066/discussion-between-rik-and-heman0128).